# Why is my red background not displaying in my table?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a mockup here

http://jsfiddle.net/Q77RZ/

Without bootstrap everything is OK.  How can I override the bootstrap settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just change the importance of that css rule so it doesn't get overwritten.

```
.red-background {
  color: black;
  background-color: red !important;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Q77RZ/4/

Answer (score 3):

You just need to make it a little more specific:

```css
table.table tbody td.red-background {
    color: black;
    background-color: red;
    font-size: 30px; 
}​
```

[Demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/Q77RZ/1/)

Comment: This is a much better option than changing the importance. Read more on specificity here: http://htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/